# Delete all subfolders and files except for a specific extension inside parent folder

Tags: matlab

I want to delete all subfolders inside a parent folder in Matlab.
I wrote the following code:

```
files=dir;
for ii = 3:1:size(files,1)
    if isdir(files(ii).folder) == 1
        rmdir (files(ii).name)
    end
end
```

However, it returns error. The first to folders are `'.'` and `'..'`.
How can I delete every folder inside ?
Also, I wrote the code below to delete every files from parent folder except Excel files (xlsx):

```
delete -except *.xlsx
```

Unlike `delvar`, the flag `-except` does not work... Any clue to it?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detecting and deleting folders, I would use the `isdir` field of the structure that is returned by [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html). You can also remove the `'.'` and `'..'` in a general way using [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) that doesn't depend on them being the first two:

```
dirData = dir();

dirList = dirData([dirData.isdir]);
dirList = dirList(~ismember({dirList.name}, {'.', '..'}));
for iDir = 1:numel(dirList)
  rmdir(fullfile(dirList(iDir).folder, dirList(iDir).name));
end
```

For the deleting the files, you can use [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to create an index of the files that don't have a '.xlsx' extension, then [delete](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delete.html) them:

```
fileList = dirData(~[dirData.isdir]);
deleteIndex = cellfun(@isempty, regexp({fileList.name}, '.xlsx'));
deleteList = fullfile({fileList(deleteIndex).folder}, {fileList(deleteIndex).name});
delete(deleteList{:});
```

Note that I used [`fullfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) in the above to build a full path to each file using the `folder` and `name`  fields of the structure returned by `dir`. This gives you the option of performing operations on a folder without having it as the current directory.

Comment: Thanks!! Works like a charm!!

Comment: I just had to add `'s'` to the `rmdir(fullfile(dirList(iDir).folder, dirList(iDir).name));` otherwise it would not delete existing folders!! Many thanks man!